# Does Phoenix Framework allow nested resource inside another nested resource?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Can I have such a thing in Phoenix as long as nested resource is concerned

```
resources "/landlords", LandlordController do
  resources "/houses", HouseController do
    resources "/units", UnitController
  end
end
```

Where I have landlord has_many houses and house also has_many units. Or any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by doing this

```
resources "/landlords", LandlordController do
  resources "/houses", HouseController
end

resources "/houses", HouseController do
 resources "/units", UnitController
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible and it's quite common. This is the best to achieve that. Please read a [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#resources/4-nested-resources) to get more information and there's also example how routes look like in such case.

```
resources "/users", UserController do
  resources "/posts", PostController
end
```

generate routes

```
user_post_path  GET     /users/:user_id/posts           PostController :index
user_post_path  GET     /users/:user_id/posts/:id/edit  PostController :edit
user_post_path  GET     /users/:user_id/posts/new       PostController :new
user_post_path  GET     /users/:user_id/posts/:id       PostController :show
user_post_path  POST    /users/:user_id/posts           PostController :create
user_post_path  PATCH   /users/:user_id/posts/:id       PostController :update
                PUT     /users/:user_id/posts/:id       PostController :update
user_post_path  DELETE  /users/:user_id/posts/:id       PostController :delete
```

Comment: because i tried and with this (landlord_house_unit) path i get an error that it does not exists

Comment: Try `mix phx.routes` to see the routes.